# Angular validation are not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to validate my password field with pattern and max length using Angular.js but in my case it is not working as per expected. My code is below.

```
<form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="signupform">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class=" control-label col-sm-3">New password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div ng-class="{ 'myError': signupform.password.$touched && signupform.password.$invalid }">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="create your new password" ng-model="first_pass" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="signupform.password.$error" ng-if="signupform.password.$touched">
                        <p ng-message="maxlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too long.The maximum length of your password should be 20.</p>
                         <p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs the format like at least one number,one letter.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class=" control-label col-sm-3">Confirm password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <div ng-class="{ 'myError': signupform.password_confirmation.$touched && signupform.password_confirmation.$invalid }">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="confirm your new password" ng-model="second_pass" ng-maxlength="8" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="signupform.password_confirmation.$error" ng-if="signupform.password_confirmation.$touched">
                        <p ng-message="maxlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too long.The maximum length of your password should be 20.</p>
                         <p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs the format like at least one number,one letter.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->                                 
                        <div class="  col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                            <button id="btn-signup" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="resetPass(signupform);">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>                             
                </form>
```

Here I need the password field should take `at least one number and one character` and maximum length should be 20. In my case both error messages are coming any case.

Comment: since password field validates the conditions why do we need to validate it again, you should use the confirm password field to validate confirm password and password are the same and if not show an error.

Comment: What's the angular version for the application?

Comment: I am using `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/"` actually my need is the password should have at least one letter and character  mandotary.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate below two messages with different condition :

```
`<p  ng-message="maxlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too long.The 
  maximum length of your password should be 20.</p>
```

`<p ng-message="pattern" style="color:#F00;">This field needs the format like at least one number,one letter.</p>`